# In Ionic2 Leaflet marker is not accept Draggable feature?

Tags: angular, leaflet, ionic2

In this code `{draggable:'true'}`feature is not accepted and makes error:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as Leaflet from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-street',
  templateUrl: 'street.html'
})
export class StreetPage {
 private latLng: any;
  private marker: any;
  private map: any;  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.drawMap();
  }
  drawMap(): void {
    let map = Leaflet.map('map');
    Leaflet.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 15
    }).addTo(map);

    map.locate({ setView: true});
    function onLocationFound(e) {      
      var radius = e.accuracy / 3;     
      Leaflet.marker(e.latlng, {draggable:'true'}).addTo(map);
      Leaflet.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    //alert on location error
    function onLocationError(e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
  }   
}
```

any Idea to solve it?

**Update:**

error for `{draggable:'true'}` :

> **Typescript Error**
>    Argument of type '{ draggable: string; }' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'MarkerOptions'. Types of property
>   'draggable' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type
>   'boolean

error for `{draggable: true}` :

> **Typescript Error** Argument of type '{ draggable: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MarkerOptions'. Property 'options' is
>   missing in type '{ draggable: true

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @n00b I have updated the post with errors shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first use

```
{draggable:true}
```

here, true is a boolean instead of your 'true' which is a string. 
TypeScript sees your code as an object with a string property which can not be assigned to a variable which is an object with a boolean property named 'draggable'

The type that is expected also needs an 'options' property. you should be able to figure out what you should put in options by looking at the definition of MarkerOptions.

You have probably downloaded some Typings (.d.ts) for 'leaflet' that is putting some definition for MarkerOptions that is too limiting.

let's say you have used this to get this typings

> npm install @types/leaflet

Option1: Find the declarations made for MarkerOptions and either change it to fit your purpose or change your parameters to match that definition.

Option2: Find the declaration for the 'marker' function in the declaration file you have downloaded and change the second parameter's type from 'MarkerOption' to 'any'

eventually your index.d.ts should look like this

```
   export interface MarkerOptions extends InteractiveLayerOptions {
        icon?: Icon;
        clickable?: boolean;
        draggable?: boolean;
        keyboard?: boolean;
        title?: string;
        alt?: string;
        zIndexOffset?: number;
        opacity?: number;
        riseOnHover?: boolean;
        riseOffset?: number;

        options?: DivIconOptions;
    }

    export class Marker extends Layer {
        constructor(latlng: LatLngExpression, options?: MarkerOptions);
        getLatLng(): LatLng;
        setLatLng(latlng: LatLngExpression): this;
        setZIndexOffset(offset: number): this;
        setIcon(icon: Icon): this;
        setOpacity(opacity: number): this;
        getElement(): HTMLElement;

        // Properties
        options: MarkerOptions;
        dragging: Handler;
    }
```

Comment: Dear @n00b this guide gives me an Idea to check the content of file and I find  may I have to use `Leaflet.marker(e.latlng, {'draggable':true} ).addTo(map);` now marker is draggable but the circle is not dragging with maker(it is not binding with marker ) another question is how to read dragged marker position. in qoogle there was a 'draggend' event listener.